# Detect a keypress when a div element is visible

Tags: jquery, gallery, lightbox, keypress

I am making a light box gallery widget, now i need to detect the keypress and call to a function but only when the `#lightbox` element is visible, and if it is not, it should ignore the key press, using jquery, i tried the following:

```
        $("#lightbox").keyup(function(e) {
alert(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { alert("a") }   // esc
});
```

any sugestion guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($('#lightbox:visible').length && e.keyCode==27) {
```

or

```
if ($('#lightbox').is(':visible') && e.keyCode==27) {
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.is(selector)` for this. It will check if the current selector holds, (if #lightbox == #lightbox:hidden

```
$("#lightbox").keyup(function (e) {
    if($("#lightbox").is(":visible")) {
        ... //your code hear
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/